# Qt applcation Scribble- accessing pixel location

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on this Qt app called scribble. Below is the link

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-scribble-example.html

I am new to Qt. I want to store the pixel locations of the scribbles(drawn using my mouse pointer) that I draw as [i],[j] values (2d values) and pass them to another function. Where can I access the pixel values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to `QImage image;` variable to read the pixel data of that scribble example. So, if you have pixel coordinates `[i][j]`, then use `pixel()` method:

```
QRgb rgb = image.pixel(i, j);
```